# Problem inserting a checkbox into a toolstrip in winforms

Tags: c#, checkbox

[Drop Down List with spurious entry][2]I have an application created some years ago in Visual Studio 2010. It extensively uses a checkbox in many of the toolstrips in the app. All of them work perfectly.

I have recently started to create a new app in WS 2019 using much of the code from the old app. All is OK except the checkboxes in the toolstrips. When I try to insert a checkbox into any of the forms toolstrips the checkbox is not in the dropdown. Furthermore, there is a spurious item in the list called crtoolstriptectbox which appears below the separator where the checkbox item was expected. This spurious entry actually works inserting a textbox (which is not wanted).

The class that is supposed to insert a checkbox in any of the toolstrips does not. however if I create a new test solution and copy in the class then insert a toolstrip in a test form it works perfectly and the spurious crtoolstriptectbox does not appear.

I have searched the whole app looking for an instance of the spurious item and nothing comes up. I have tried creating a new solution and copied all the files from the nonworking version but the result is the same. The spurious entry appears in the dropdown list and the checkbox does not appear. I cannot create a checkbox in the toolstrip in any of the forms.

here is the code I am using...

I have searched the whole app looking for an instance of the spurious item and nothing comes up. I have tried creating a new solution and copied all the files from the nonworking version but the result is the same. The spurious entry appears in the dropdown list and the checkbox does not appear. I cannot create a checkbox in the toolstrip in any of the forms.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
using System.Drawing;
namespace tt
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]

    [ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.ToolStrip)]
    // [ToolboxBitmap(@"..\..\Images\CheckBox.bmp")]
    public class ToolStripCheckBox : ToolStripControlHost
    {

        public ToolStripCheckBox()
            : base(new CheckBox())
        { }

        public CheckBox checkBoxControl
        {
            get
            {
                return Control as CheckBox;
            }
        }

        public bool isChecked
        {
            get
            {
                return checkBoxControl.Checked;
            }
            set
            {
                checkBoxControl.Checked = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnSubscribeControlEvents(Control c)
        {
            // Call the base so the base events are connected.

            base.OnSubscribeControlEvents(c);

            // Cast the control to a MonthCalendar control.

            CheckBox CheckBoxControl = (CheckBox)c;

            // Add the event.

            CheckBoxControl.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(OnCheckedChanged);
        }

        protected override void OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(Control c)
        {
            // Call the base method so the basic events are unsubscribed.

            base.OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(c);

            // Cast the control to a MonthCalendar control.

            CheckBox CheckBoxControl = (CheckBox)c;
```

Comment: A picture would really help, we are not going to be able to answer this based on this info - you need to narrow it down

Comment: I can't find out to add an image here

Comment: There's a toolstrip of buttons when you [edit] your question, the button with a Camera icon

Comment: I tried to include the image by dragging and dropping and go the following 'Your edit couldn't be submitted. Please see the errors above' but there was no errors above.

Comment: The drop down list looks like this...

Comment: Now I can't even type what I want. This is a terrible use interface!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. You're asking where some control appears out of no where and describe that with 5 paragraphs, yet none of the info you've given is helpful. How are we supposed to troubleshoot a GUI problem when we can't see the designer code or any code to setup and position of the checkboxes - you've just shown us their event handlers which has nothing to do with the problem. There's a point where you can only *help* so much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I was implementing the use of a checkbox in a toolstrip while there were still many errors in the solution brought over from the original application. Thus at that time the new app would not compile.
I was thus running a build that failed (I knew it would). I was assuming that the class that was managing the creation of the required checkbox and adding it into the toolstrip would just ‘save’ as all the files do in a compile and all would be good.
I found the result when I cleaned up the 50 or so errors sitting in the solution. I was then able to run a successful compile and ‘hey presto’ the system worked exactly as required. The dropdown list on the toolstrip now displays the ‘checkbox’ and clicking it installs a checkbox correctly. 
Thanks to those that responded to this question.